# How to retrieve sorted records from an hdf table

Tags: hdf5, pytables, hdf

I'm looking for a way to retrieve sorted records from an `hdf` table. Here is a python MWE:

```
import tables
import numpy as np

class Measurement(tables.IsDescription):
    time = tables.Float64Col()
    value = tables.Float64Col()

h5 = tables.open_file('test.hdf', 'w')
h5.create_table('/', 'test', Measurement)

table = h5.root.test
data = np.array([(0, 6), (5, 1), (1, 8)], dtype=[('time', '<f8'), ('value', '<f8')])
table.append(data)
table.cols.time.createCSIndex()
```

Now I'd like to retrieve all records with `time > 0`, sorted by `time`. If I do:

```
table.read_where('time > 0')
```

then it gets:

```
array([(5.0, 1.0), (1.0, 8.0)], dtype=[('time', '<f8'), ('value', '<f8')])
```

which is not sorted by `time`. If I attempt to use `read_sorted` then I get the entire table instead of a subset (there's no condition argument to `read_sorted`).

What is the common practice? Should I ensure that my tables are stored sorted in the database? Or should I sort myself the retrieved set after `read_where`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a one size fits all answer to your question.

If you are in a situation where you write once to the file and have to read it a lot of times, it would definitely be a good idea to store the tables in a sorted manner. For already existing files, you can use the `ptrepack` utility which can copy exisiting data in a sorted manner.

If you only read the data a few times, the storing in a sorted way might not be the most efficient way. Just `read_where` to get your data into memory and sort afterwards.

If your data is to big to fit into memory, you'll have to store the data in a sorted manner.

And there are more possibilities, depending on your system perfomance (SSD, HDD, network storage, CPU,...)